# I want to make position sticky on the right side for sidebar and scrollable div on the left side using CSS Only

Tags: html, css, sass

Any pure css to make use of sticky sidebar on right side and scrollable div on left side.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please upload code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

For making a sticky element : use `position : sticky;`
then you can specify, where you want your element to stop, for example `top`, `right`, `left` or `bottom`.
For example : `position : sticky ;`
`right : 0 ;`

You can read more about sticky element here - [How TO - Sticky Element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

For scrolling of div : use `overflow : auto` or `overflow : scroll`.
You can read more about the `overflow` property here - [CSS overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

If you want a fixed element, use `position : fixed`. Then specify where you want your element to appear. You can read more about it here - [CSS position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)